# How can the linear-time cost of Blender's .children Python property be avoided in scenes with many objects?

Tags: python, development

While working on optimizing an add-on that creates/manages a large number of objects, I noticed that invocations of `bpy_types.Object.children` accounted for an unusually large proportion of run-time (30 of 60 seconds in a small-scale example, after optimizing most other simple inefficiencies). My profiler pointed me back to [this bit of Blender's Python API source](https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/b73dc36859e03845f702a3e985b536ac9afef63a/release/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py#L114-L121):

```
    @property
    def children(self):
        """All the children of this object.
        .. note:: Takes ``O(len(bpy.data.objects))`` time."""
        import bpy
        return tuple(child for child in bpy.data.objects
                     if child.parent == self)
```

I was shocked to see `.children` is just a simple linear search over all objects in `bpy.data.objects` (which is obviously very expensive when managing a large number of objects), rather than maintaining a graph of parent-child relations updated each time an object is created, deleted, or parented/unparented. (It also bears comment that this pattern is re-used in many places in `bpy_types`, including but not limited to: `users_dupli_group` for `Collection`; `users_collection`, `users_scene` for `Object`; and `children` for `_GenericBone`. An important case where I was not able to verify behavior is `children` for `bpy_types.Collection`, which seems to be defined in the Blender C source, which I struggled somewhat to navigate)

This cost is not very noticeable in scenes with a small number of objects, but can be prohibitively expensive in scenes with a large number of objects.  I've opened [a proposed Blender source change](https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/L7Mr/) to suggest addressing this, but, in the meantime: are there natural ways to avoid this cost in standard `Add On` development, using the usual Blender Python API?

Comment: Thanks for this, good to know.  _esp_ that it takes from all blend file object datablocks.  Makes sense re a consistency of result  basis.  From now on will make  a defaultdict from scene objects.  Wonder is same for collections>?   Agree that it is not a suitable question for BSE to ask why, whereas would consider re-jigging into how to work around it (your use case)  and  add an answer.

Comment: Can make suggestions at https://blender.community/c/rightclickselect/?sorting=hot  and / or join and submit patch to https://developer.blender.org

Comment: Hm--not sure on collections. There's no defn for `.children` in https://github.com/blender/blender/blob/b73dc36859e03845f702a3e985b536ac9afef63a/release/scripts/modules/bpy_types.py#L100-L108, and I'm not familiar enough with the Blender C source to track down `bpy_types.ID`, where I assume the collection `.children` is defined. That same comprehension pattern is present in a lot of places in `bpy_types` where some notion of children is needed, though -- eg, in various places in `bones`, and, in, `Object`, for `users_collection` and `users_scene`. Some of these are usually small, so maybe OK

Comment: And thanks! Will edit this question/answer it in a more BSE-friendly form when I have a moment later today, and will take a look to see if I can make a useful suggestion on the Blender community link you gave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest work-around I was able to determine for this problem is to cache object-child and object-ancestor relationships into dictionaries that I build and update myself, and replacing wherever possible `.children` references with references to this globally maintained dictionary (which must itself be updated when objects are deleted, parenting relationships are altered, etc, to avoid `KeyError` problems or mapping parent objects to objects whose Blender `mRNA` has been removed, etc).

To illustrate, here's a toy code snippet that does some simple profiling, in a scene with `3,473` total objects (a small-scale example, in my setting, but with enough objects to make the difference in behavior obvious), with a `bpy.context.active_object` that has `5` child objects (small relative to the number of total objects), to compare caching to a dictionary versus use of the standard `.children` property:

```
import cProfile, bpy, pstats
NUM_REPETITIONS = 100000

def linearTimeChildrenExample():
    cur_name = ""
    for _ in range(NUM_REPETITIONS):
        for c in bpy.context.active_object.children:
            cur_name = c.name

def cacheObjects():
    obj2Children = {}
    for obj in bpy.data.objects:
        obj2Children[obj] = [c for c in obj.children]
    bpy.types.Scene.obj2Children = obj2Children #NOTE: useful hack for assigning a globally accessible dictionary tracking parent-child relations

def cachedDictChildrenExample():
    cacheObjects()
    cur_name = ""
    for _ in range(NUM_REPETITIONS):
        for c in bpy.types.Scene.obj2Children[bpy.context.active_object]:
            cur_name = c.name

def runExamples():
    print(f"NUM_REPETITIONS is: {NUM_REPETITIONS}")
    print(f"{bpy.context.active_object} has # children: {len(bpy.types.Scene.obj2Children[bpy.context.active_object])}")
    linearTimeChildrenExample()
    cachedDictChildrenExample()

def profileExamples():
    profiler = cProfile.Profile()
    profiler_filepath = bpy.path.abspath("//") + "example_profiler_output.profiled"
    profiler.runcall(runExamples, *[], **{})
    profiler.dump_stats(profiler_filepath)
    ps = pstats.Stats(profiler_filepath)
    print("------------ ps dump of linearTimeChildren profiler output ------------")
    ps.strip_dirs().sort_stats('cumulative').print_stats()
```

For small numbers of "repetitions", the cost of caching is about the same as just using `.children` directly (since caching requires using `.children` originally, unless you have a clever naming convention or some other way to know exactly which objects to reference in initially building a dictionary of parent-child relationships), but for large numbers of repetitions (like the `100,000` used here, with a cheap operation in each iteration), we get a stark difference:

```
         724637 function calls in 76.739 seconds

   Ordered by: cumulative time

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000   76.739   76.739 linearTimeChildren.py:24(runExamples)
   106588    0.269    0.000   76.183    0.001 bpy_types.py:119(children)
   611453   75.914    0.000   75.914    0.000 bpy_types.py:123(<genexpr>)
        1    0.412    0.412   71.916   71.916 linearTimeChildren.py:5(linearTimeChildrenExample)
        1    0.130    0.130    4.823    4.823 linearTimeChildren.py:17(cachedDictChildrenExample)
        1    0.013    0.013    4.693    4.693 linearTimeChildren.py:11(cacheObjects)
     6588    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 linearTimeChildren.py:14(<listcomp>)
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.print}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {built-in method builtins.len}
```

Essentially all of the `4.823` secs spent in `cachedDictChildrenExample` was actually just spent caching the relationships into a dictionary originally, in `cacheObjects` (`4.693` secs), so this seems like a reasonable workaround. By contrast, iterating over `.children` for the same number of repetitions obviously takes a much longer time, at `71.916` secs. It may also be worth noting the explicit cumulative-time estimates for the `bpy_types.Object.children` and the associated `<generator expression>`: both about 75 seconds, with 72 of that in the linear example and about 4.5 of it in the cached dictionary example (so, clearly, `.children` calls are the dominant cost, here).

NOTE: in practice, unlike in this script, I tend to cache names of objects (for both parent and child objects) rather than references to the objects themselves. This often seems to allow for more graceful handling of Blender objects that have been removed procedurally, and, generally, for avoiding any conflicts with assumptions made internally about Blender's handling of object references.

Comment: "I tend to cache names of objects" Note that names are not unique if you link things from a different .blend. I think `(ob.name, ob.library.name if ob.library else None)` is unique though.

Answer (score 3):

The `cacheObjects()` function can do only one pass through the object list, which might be faster.

```
obj2Children = {}

for obj in bpy.data.objects:
    # Add to parent's child list
    if obj.parent is not None:
        obj2Children.setdefault(obj.parent, []).append(obj)

    # Make sure childless objects get an empty list
    obj2Children.setdefault(obj, [])
```

(And like batFINGER said, you could also use a `defaultdict`.)

A default dictionary where any key defaults to an empty list.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> children = defaultdict(list)
>>> for o in D.objects:
...     children[o.parent].append(o)
...
```

All top level (no parent) objects.

```
>>> children[None]
[bpy.data.objects['Camera'], bpy.data.objects['Cube'], bpy.data.objects['Lamp']]
```

Other members in keys collection directly after running are those with children.

```
>>> children.keys()
dict_keys([None])
```

Children of the lamp

```
>>> children[D.objects['Lamp']]
[]
```

Comment: Oh, that's a lovely point. I had considered using a `defaultdict` but it didn't seem any more elegant or efficient, to me; I was not specifically thinking about further optimizing the way the caching function works, though. Switching it to make just a single pass is certainly beneficial

Comment: @scurest thought I'd add a simple dd example to  answer  Possibly get a squeak more by not testing for `None`.