# How to efficiently add approximately 30000 correctly oriented cylinders into blender via Python

Tags: python, scripting

I am working on an illustration for my PhD thesis that will show all interactions commonly included in the molecular quantum Hamiltonian operator.

My idea is as follows:

1. Add all nuclei as ico spheres
2. Add electrons around the nuclei as tiny spheres
3. Add all nuclei-nuclei (NN) interactions as cylinders
4. Add all electron-electron (ee) interactions as cylinders
5. Add all nuclei-electron (Ne) interactions as cylinders

I separate steps 3-5 so that I easily can keep track of the nature of the interactions and color them differently.

The molecule I want to show is a 54-atom transition metal complex, with 234 electrons.

The number of unique pair interactions $N$ for a set of $n$ particles is

$$
N = \frac{n(n-1)}{2}
$$

This amounts to 1431 unique NN interactions and 27261 ee interactions, and the number Ne interactions which I have not calculated.

The first couple of thousand cylinders are relatively efficient, then it becomes much slower. At around 10000 the script adds about 1 cylinder per second, and so I stopped it there. However, I would like to include all the interactions.

Is there a way to achieve this in an efficient way? Could I use an array modifier, and still be able to orient the cylinders correctly? If it is not feasible, then I can always choose a smaller molecule.

Here is the script I use:

```py
import bpy
import numpy as np
import math
from itertools import combinations


settings = {
        'H': 1,
        'C': 6,
        'N': 7,
        'O': 8,
        'Ni': 28
    }


def fiboSphere(n=100, origo=(0, 0, 0), r=1):
    goldenRatio = (1 + 5**0.5)/2
    
    grid = np.arange(0, n)
    theta = np.pi * grid / goldenRatio
    phi = np.arccos(1 - 2 * (grid) / n)
    
    x = r * np.cos(theta) * np.sin(phi) + origo[0]
    y = r * np.sin(theta) * np.sin(phi) + origo[1]
    z = r * np.cos(phi) + origo[2]
    
    return zip(x, y, z)

def readCoords(f):
    with open(f) as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
        labels = [line.split()[0] for line in lines[2:]]
        coords = np.asarray([list(map(float, line.split()[1:])) for line in lines[2:]])
        
        masses = [settings[lab] for lab in labels]
    
    return labels, coords - np.average(coords, axis=0, weights=masses)

def addSphere(x, y, z, r=1):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_uv_sphere_add(radius=r, location=(x, y, z))
    #bpy.ops.outliner.item_rename('Nuclei')
    
def addIcoSphere(x, y, z, r=1):
    bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_ico_sphere_add(subdivisions=1, radius=r, location=(x, y, z))
    
def cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dz = z2 - z1    
    dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)

    ob = bpy.ops.mesh.primitive_cylinder_add(
        radius = r, 
        depth = dist,
        location = (dx/2 + x1, dy/2 + y1, dz/2 + z1)   
      ) 

    phi = math.atan2(dy, dx) 
    theta = math.acos(dz/dist) 

    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[1] = theta 
    bpy.context.object.rotation_euler[2] = phi


if __name__ == '__main__':
    SPHERES = 0
    LINE_NUCS = 0
    LINE_ELECS = 1
    
    molecule = 'Ni-NHC2.xyz'
    
    r_elec = 0.05
    r_nuc = r_elec * 3
    r_atom = r_nuc * 3
    r_cyl = 0.0001

    atoms, coords = readCoords(molecule)
    
    if SPHERES == 1:
        for a, c in zip(atoms, coords):
            if a == 'Ni':
                addIcoSphere(*c, r=r_nuc * np.sqrt(settings[a]/4))
            else:
                addIcoSphere(*c, r=r_nuc * np.sqrt(settings[a]/2))
                
                
            for elec in fiboSphere(n=settings[a], origo=c, r=r_atom):
                addSphere(*elec, r=r_elec)
            
    
    if LINE_NUCS == 1:
        natoms = len(coords)
        combos = list(combinations(np.arange(natoms), 2))
        for i, combo in enumerate(combos):
            print(i, len(combos))
            i, j = combo
            xA, yA, zA = coords[i]
            xB, yB, zB = coords[j]
            
            cylinder_between(xA, yA, zA, xB, yB, zB, r_cyl)
            
            
    if LINE_ELECS == 1:
        nelecs = 0
        for a in atoms:
            nelecs += settings[a]
        
        combos = list(combinations(np.arange(nelecs), 2))
        all_elecs = []
        for a, c in zip(atoms, coords):
            for elec in fiboSphere(n=settings[a], origo=c, r=r_atom):
                all_elecs.append(elec)
                
        curr = 3000
        for i, combo in enumerate(combos[curr:curr+500]):
            print(i+curr, len(combos))
            i, j = combo
            xA, yA, zA = all_elecs[i]
            xB, yB, zB = all_elecs[j]
            cylinder_between(xA, yA, zA, xB, yB, zB, r_cyl)
```

and here are the coordinates for the molecule:

```
54

Ni         0.53508        2.94170       -1.19095
C          0.89172        2.78025        0.55921
C          0.13343        1.34854       -1.93501
C         -0.80330        4.11901       -1.38999
O         -0.19137        0.31584       -2.35779
O          1.09923        2.70358        1.70102
O         -1.66995        4.88913       -1.48201
H          0.51175        2.95147       -6.22064
C          1.10271        3.13388       -5.30374
H          0.84068        0.57894       -6.28354
H          1.83440        3.94105       -5.51296
H          0.41920        3.51974       -4.51700
H          0.02746        7.62618       -2.63086
H          1.69364        7.30829       -3.21356
C          0.88136        6.92729       -2.55858
C          1.51452        0.62494       -5.41305
H          1.50838       -1.80537       -6.60596
H          0.56578        5.95106       -2.97683
C          1.77035        1.87351       -4.82202
C          1.73376       -1.89724       -5.52533
H          0.13563        8.40984       -0.37790
C          2.07482       -0.56412       -4.90989
C          1.34936        6.78856       -1.13348
H          0.83330       -2.32912       -5.03778
C          2.62737        1.90396       -3.70207
C          0.87912        7.63910       -0.11886
H          2.55568       -2.62944       -5.40126
C          3.95328        4.00413       -3.41477
N          2.89355        3.16567       -3.07152
H          4.66590        3.74492       -4.20292
C          2.12853        3.69055       -2.05863
C          3.86116        5.09719       -2.59552
N          2.74966        4.88583       -1.78318
H          4.47675        5.99767       -2.51503
C          2.28833        5.79755       -0.77436
C          2.91681       -0.48577       -3.78475
H          0.54777        9.43656        1.90824
C          3.20418        0.73782       -3.15710
C          1.32300        7.52594        1.21247
C          0.75840        8.41761        2.28950
H         -0.20145        8.01023        2.67381
H          3.35077       -1.40920       -3.36894
C          2.78466        5.66588        0.53957
C          2.28179        6.54227        1.51721
C          4.03233        0.81322       -1.90217
H          3.39997        1.15882       -1.05618
H          1.44677        8.50453        3.15264
H          4.86553        1.53987       -1.99398
C          3.82449        4.62798        0.87242
H          4.80908        4.88876        0.42895
H          4.45676       -0.17386       -1.63994
H          3.54684        3.63357        0.47078
H          2.64748        6.44572        2.55195
H          3.95682        4.53377        1.96626
```

And a rendered image of some of the NN interactions:

[image]

## Update

I was able to use `bmesh` to add the cylinders, and to align them correctly, in this way:

(with credit to [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/30640/133529) for the original idea)

```py
def cylinder_between(x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, r, id=''):
    dx = x2 - x1
    dy = y2 - y1
    dz = z2 - z1    
    dist = math.sqrt(dx**2 + dy**2 + dz**2)
    loc = np.asarray((x1 + dx/2, y1 + dy/2, z1 + dz/2))
    
    name = f'Cylinder_{id}'
    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    bpy.context.collection.objects.link(obj)
    
    bm = bmesh.new()
    cone = bmesh.ops.create_cone(bm, 
                                 cap_ends=True, 
                                 cap_tris=False, 
                                 segments=3, 
                                 diameter1=r_cyl, 
                                 diameter2=r_cyl, 
                                 depth=dist)
                                 
    obj.location.x = loc[0]
    obj.location.y = loc[1]
    obj.location.z = loc[2]
        
    phi = math.atan2(dy, dx) 
    theta = math.acos(dz/dist)
    
    obj.rotation_euler[1] = theta 
    obj.rotation_euler[2] = phi
        
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    bm.free()
```

Comment: There's probably more you'll have to optimize than this, but one thing I think you'll want to avoid are `bpy.ops.mesh` calls. I believe operators induce a scene update, which walks over all scene objects, and as a result doing so `N` times induces `N^2` run-time problems

Comment: `Atomic blender` is able to add tens of thousands of atoms in a few seconds, with bonds and everything. So it should be doable, I feel. I just don't know enough about the workflow and the API to know where to start. Perhaps my bonds don't need to be cylinders, but curves with a thickness..

Comment: before I dive into this, I have to ask, doesn't your department have molecule visualization software that can do this sort of thing?  Purpose built tools are usually more efficient.

Comment: I am sure I could do this with PyMOL, but the shading is a bit limited. Besides, high impact graphics in our field require Blender knowledge, so why not dive in and try to learn :)

Comment: Cool.  Your problem is probably what @NeverConvex suggested, so the trick is to use bmesh to create the meshes so that screen updates don't get called as often.  Can you live with everything in one object, if individual meshes have their own materials?

Comment: Yes, as long as I can color the different atoms differently, and color the different interactions differently, then I am happy. Thanks for looking at this! I am able to generate the cylinders with bmesh (and it seems to be **much** faster, but I am not able to orient them correctly...

Comment: you need to use bmesh transform operations for that [this page](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.ops.html) has examples.  if you can't figure it out, post your bmesh code, it's what I was about to create and why duplicate?

Comment: Q updated. It took 600 seconds to load all the objects. Do you have additional suggestions?

Comment: Before trying to further optimize, you might consider profiling your code to identify where it is spending most of its time. In my experience, Blender's Python API is very compatible with the usual Python CProfiler; I have an example of doing so in this question, if you'd like to try: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/229469/73773

Comment: Similar question: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233755/blender-taking-too-long-to-create-an-object-with-python-code